# Select values that exist in all arrays in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got some table `ignore` with col `ignored_entry_ids` contains array of integer. For example:

```
id     ignored_entry_ids
1      {1,4,6}
2      {6,8,11}
3      {5,6,7}
```

How can I select numbers that exists in every row with array? (6 in examle)

Comment: What exactly is the result you want? What should be the result if you query for the number 5?

Comment: Result is array of enrty_id (from `ignored_entry_ids` column) that ignored by all users. In other words^ numbers that exists in all rows in `ignored_entry_ids` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your numbers are unique inside array, you can do something like this, don't think it could be made without `unnest`

```
with cte as (
    select id, unnest(ignored_entry_ids) as arr
    from ign
)
select arr
from cte
group by arr
having count(*) = (select count(*) from ign)
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8a314/1)

if numbers are not unique, add `distinct`:

```
with cte as (
    select distinct id, unnest(ignored_entry_ids) as arr
    from ign
)
select arr
from cte
group by arr
having count(*) = (select count(*) from ign)
```